# AutoML colab notebook ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'gcsfs'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I'm running the AutoML notebook from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/tables/automl/notebooks/purchase_prediction/purchase_prediction.ipynb

In Colab the following line:

```
table = pd.read_csv(nested_gcs_uri, low_memory=False)
```

fails with the error in the subject.

I've tried pip install gcsfs which reports `Requirement already satisfied`

Import gcsfs returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gcsfs'
```

Comment: Hey! I've run notebook in AI Platform->Jupyter Nootebok and it works fine. Have you restarted the kernel after libs installation? Additionally, have you specified ENV variables correctly?

Comment: Were you using the Colab environment hosted runtime?

Comment: I've used AI Platform Notebooks. I copied all commands to the notebook, so it's basically the same as Collab. Remember, before running any command you need to make sure that billing is enabled for your project and enable: AI Platform APIs, Compute Engine APIs, AutoML API.

Comment: YEs, thanks - I've set up the billing and API's etc. This appears to be a pure Python dependency error

Comment: I'll suggest to try with AI Platform Notebooks, it could be an error inside Colab environment.

Comment: @muscat - yes, going to that - agree it may be a Colab issue. I have logged on Github https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/3409

Comment: do you agree that I will post an answer with above information (with a link to github) to let community know about the issue?

Comment: @muscat sure, please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `Purchase Prediction with AutoML Tables` [notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/tables/automl/notebooks/purchase_prediction/purchase_prediction.ipynb) works perfectly on `AI Platform Notebooks` in GCP. Before running any command it's important to make sure that billing, AI Platform API, Compute Engine API, AutoML API are enabled in GCP project. For some reasons it throws an error while running in Colab environment. The bug has been already reported on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/3409) by @Matt Evans.

Comment: Google support have responded: thank you for bringing this to light. it looks like the notebook wasn't written for colab. i'll investigate whether we can make this notebook runnable from colab.